# Perl: How to print WWW::Curl::Form content?

Tags: perl, curl

I have a `my $curlf = WWW::Curl::Form->new;` variable, and I'd like to check its content.

I've tried to do a

`print Dumper($curlf) if($verbose);`

but got the following result:

`$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 151334456)}, 'WWW::Curl::Form' );`

What's the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WWW::Curl::Form` is not a proper Perl data structure, it is just a scalar reference to a C data structure buried in XS code, which itself is (at least partly) a wrapper around some `libcurl` library functions.

If you can program in C, the correct way to check its content is to extend the XS code using the right `libcurl` function calls to extract info from a pair of `curl_httppost` data structures. Then send a patch to the module's maintainer.

If you can't program in C, then send the module maintainer a feature request for the next version of the module.